# Set Query Builder conditions to Model in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, model

First I have to say that I tried to find solution, and i didn't.

**Basic question:**

```
$Br = new BrandTop;
dd( $Br->limit(10)->get() ); // Will return 10 rows
```

and

```
$Br = new BrandTop;
$Br->limit(10);
dd( $Br->get() ); // Will return all rows.
```

So, the basic question - why? How can I set some limit for Model, but still work with it, for example set (or not set) some **where** or **order** depends on other variables.

**Advanced question:**

I want to use Model like this:

```
class BrandTop extends Model
{
    public function withBrand() {
        return $this->leftJoin('brand', 'brand.id' , '=', 'brandtop.brand_id');
    }
    public function forType($type) // there is much more conditions for type
    {
        return $this->where(['type' => $type]);
    }

    // main function
    public function forSunglasses($limit = 0, $logo = false)
    {
        if ($logo)
            $this->where(['menu_logo' => 1])->orderBy('total_sales', 'desc');
        if ($limit)
            $this->limit($limit);

        return $this->forType('sunglasses')->withBrand();
        // But there goes Error, because forType() return Builder object, and it has no withBrand() method
    }
}
```

So, there is much more conditions, and it's much easier to set all conditions in separate methods. But how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Model vs Builder

The thing to understand here is the difference between the `Model` object and the underlying `Builder` (query builder) object.

The statement `$Br = new BrandTop;` will create a new instance of a `Model`, and assign it to the `$Br` variable. Next, the `$Br->limit(10)` statement will create a new instance of a `Builder` object for the brand_tops table, with a limit of 10 applied.

In your first example, by doing `$Br->limit(10)->get()`, you're calling `get()` on the `Builder` that has your limit applied.

In your second example, your individual `$Br->limit(10)` creates the new `Builder` instance, but never uses it for anything. The next statement, `$Br->get()`, creates another new `Builder` instance without any constraints, so it retrieves all the records.

To be able to build up your query, you need to assign your `Builder` instance to a variable, and continue to modify that instance before finally calling `get()`. For example, to get your second example to work:

```
$query = BrandTop::query();
$query->limit(10);
$query->where(/*conditions*/);
dd($query->get());
```

### Query Scopes

In relation to the second part of your question, you probably want to look into [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes).

```
class BrandTop extends Model
{
    // renamed to "JoinBrand" instead of "WithBrand", as "with" would imply
    // an eager loaded relationship vs a joined table
    public function scopeJoinBrand($query)
    {
        return $query->leftJoin('brand', 'brand.id' , '=', 'brandtop.brand_id');
    }

    // got rid of "for" prefix
    public function scopeType($query, $type)
    {
        return $query->where('type', $type);
    }

    // got rid of "for" prefix
    public function scopeSunglasses($query, $limit = 0, $logo = false)
    {
        if ($logo)
            $query->where(['menu_logo' => 1])->orderBy('total_sales', 'desc');
        if ($limit)
            $query->limit($limit);

        return $query->type('sunglasses')->joinBrand();
    }
}
```

With the above model, your code would look something like:

```
dd(BrandTop::sunglasses()->get());

// or, more verbosely:

$query = BrandTop::query();
$query->sunglasses(); // $query already an object, no need to reassign it to itself
dd($query->get());
```